# SQLite: How do I subtract the value in one row from another?

Tags: sqlite

Here is my example table:

```
column_example
10
20
25
50
```

Here is what I would like:

```
column_example2
10
5
25
```

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I haven't found the answer in the [SQLite Syntax web page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html/) or via Google.

EDIT: To clarify, the code would likely return the outputs for: 
    20-10
    25-20
    50-25

Comment: I can't understand what you want to achieve. Do you have one table with two columns, or two tables? What do you want to subtract from what? Please detail your question a bit more :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'd like to subtract the number in one row from the number in the previous row. column_example is what I have, and column_example2 would be what I want to end up with.

Comment: Do you have another column in your table which determines the order of the rows (autoincrementing id field or something else)?

Comment: Yes, it's labeled 'rowid'. Apologies for not including that -- I thought it would be assumed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution might be slow, but I had to consider the potential gaps between succeeding `rowid`s:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/daeed/1

```
SELECT
  (SELECT x
   FROM t AS t3
   WHERE t3.rowid =
     (SELECT MIN(tt.rowid)
      FROM t AS tt
      WHERE tt.rowid > t.rowid
     )
  )
  - x

FROM t
WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
```

If it is guaranteed to not have any gaps between `rowid`s, then you can use this simpler query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1f906/3

```
SELECT t_next.x - t.x
FROM       t
INNER JOIN t AS t_next
        ON t_next.rowid = t.rowid + 1
```

Comment: Yep, this works. I just had a couple questions about the code, as I'm still learning SQLite. I'm looking at the code in the first link, for context...

Comment: Line 3 says (SELECT MIN(tt.rowid). I'm guessing MIN means minimum, as in the smallest rowid number. What does 'tt' mean in this case?

Comment: `FROM t AS tt` means that the given table could be referenced by an other name (alias) in the query. There is 3 `FROM t ...` in the above query, and I gave a different alias to all of them (except the outermost one), otherwise SQLite couldn't find out what to compare/subtract with/from what.